# Calculate previous login for each row grouped by day relative to current row

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Goal:** I would like to gather logins for each user grouped by day.

**Problem:** I am struggling with the function to calculate the last column which is the last login relative to the current row of the login column(somewhat like a lag function but not sure how to use it). The issue is that I only need to show logins for the last three months so how would it calculate the fifth observation of the days_last_login column in the following table if i put a where condition for the last three months?:

**Desired Output:**

```
+----+---------------------+-----------------+
| id |        login        | days_last_login |
+----+---------------------+-----------------+
|  1 | 2018-12-10 05:00:00 |               5 |
|  1 | 2018-12-07 05:30:00 |               3 |
|  1 | 2018-12-01 05:30:00 |               6 |
|  2 | 2019-08-01 05:30:00 |               7 |
|  2 | 2019-01-01 05:30:00 |             365 |
+----+---------------------+-----------------+
```

**Current Query:**

```
    SELECT id
        ,YEAR(login) as yr, MONTH(login) as mm, DAY(login) as dd
        ,CAST(login AS DATE) as logins
        ,FUNCTION FOR DAYS_LAST_LOGIN
    FROM database.table 
    WHERE login > DATEADD(month,-3,getdate())
    GROUP BY YEAR(login), MONTH(login), DAY(login), id
    ORDER BY id, yr desc, mm desc, dd desc
```

**Note:**  I ommitted to show the yr,month and day columns in the table to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell, the logic is the number of days from a given login date to the next, presumably with the most recent date measured up to the current date.

That suggests a query like this:

```
SELECT id, CONVERT(date, login) as dte,
    DATEDIFF(day, login, LEAD(MAX(login), 1, GETDATE()) OVER (PARTITION BY id)) as DAYS_LAST_LOGIN
FROM database.table 
WHERE login > DATEADD(month, -3, getdate())
GROUP BY id, CONVERT(date, login)
ORDER BY id, CONVERT(date, login) DESC;
```

I removed the date parts because I don't find them useful, but you can of course include them.

Comment: if you remove the date parts , would it group logins by day? if i person logs in 5 times a day, will it appear once (this is what I want).

Comment: can you describe what actually `LEAD(MAX(login), 1, GETDATE()) OVER (PARTITION BY id)`does?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 . . . And yes, grouping by the *date* means there is only one row per day.

Comment: the whole function works apart from one thing. If somebody logged in 3 months ago exactly, I would see that record. But for its corresponding days_last_login value, I dont want it to be the datediff of Getdate() and Login date, it should simply be the previous login (e.g which maybe be 1 year ago) and stop there.

Comment: @RogerSteinberg . . . Then you need to use a subquery and put the `where` clause in the outer query.

Comment: Would the subquery include the whole table records?